# SqlDataAdapter is not updating datatable in the database

Tags: c#, database, datatable, sqldataadapter

I'm trying to update datatable in the database using a `SqlDataAdapter`. I don't see any errors and also it's not updating the database.

I tried other solutions in the stackoverflow but still no luck. Here is my code:

```
public void Update(DataTable dt, String tableName)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, connection);
            SqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
            da.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
            da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;

            int res = da.Update(dt);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception oEx)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Ex: " + oEx);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you expecting your code should do? Because there is no `UPDATE somthing` or similare in your code snippet. Maybe you interpreted the method `GetUpdateCommand` wrong? As [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.getupdatecommand?view=netframework-4.8) describe: 'it returns the SqlCommand object to be executed.'

Comment: @nilsK Sorry, I did not understand your question. What do you mean by there is no update? There is a Update statement in the code. `da.Update(dt);`

Comment: @user2782405 table adapters went out of fashion a decade ago. You shouldn't be using them in new code. In any case, the adapter will save the *modified* rows in the DataTable. If there are no modifications, it won't save anything. That's why the tutorials you see, or the [Update method docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.update?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_Common_DbDataAdapter_Update_System_Data_DataTable_) show loading the DataTable with Fill, *modifying* it and then calling `Update` on it

Comment: Ah, i see ... a decade ago i did not know what a database is ;)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I missed datatable with fill. Thanks for guiding me!